# Is ButterKnife memory safe with retained Fragment?

Tags: android, butterknife

```
public class GenericRetainedFragment extends GenericFragment {

    @Bind(R.id.some_button)
    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        ButterKnife.unbind(this);
    }
}
```

Since I have no idea how ButterKnife work on unbind method, affter configuration change, will memory leak occur ?

Does this a good practice using ButterKnife and Retained Fragment ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that there would be any problems with retained fragments, because the instance of the fragment should always be "alive" until it's removed.  It doesn't go into the back stack, and therefore have its views destroyed and possibly recreated (this is the normal situation with Fragments that requires a special pattern with ButterKnife).  One instance of a retained fragment will only have one set of views unless you do something to change that.

Comment: Whether the ButterKnife will clear the view reference when we call `ButterKnife.bind(this)` ? If it does, the activity be garbage collected, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, if an Activity is destroyed, then all of its components should also be destroyed unless you're doing something to hold them outside the scope of the activity.